# relationship between two system of coordinates

Tags: analysis, classical-mechanics

I Have a problem:

There are Greenwich coordinates (ECEF),$$\eta_1=2850144.282468, \eta_2=2197962.005840, \eta_3=5248530.328116.$$

Calculate the values of geographical coordinates (Geodetic), for these coordinates.

I can't find any information about relationship between these system of coordinates and literature where I can read about this. It would be great if you helped me, because I've lost a lot time to find useful information,

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Is that it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_ECEF_to_geodetic_coordinates) ?

Comment: yes, thank you!

Comment: If you scroll down @AlexeyBurdin's link, it eventually admits $\lambda$ should be calculated [with $\operatorname{arctan2}$ instead of $\arctan$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).